How do I prove that this is Context Free? L = $\{ a^i b^j c^k \mid k = i \times j \text{ and } 0 < i < 10 < j \}$
I've been trying to use the pumping lemma to prove that it is not context free however, im not sure what to do with the bound 0<i<10<j.
I'm pretty sure it's not context free because I couldn't think of a grammar that would accept k=i*j since it would give you infinite possibilities.
Maybe I am wrong, I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this!
EDIT:
I can make a CFG for a specific value of i such as i=4:
\begin{align*}
S &\to \text{aaaa}B \\
B &\to bB\text{cccc} \mid \lambda
\end{align*}
However, how would I prove this more formally? Do I just create a CFG for every value of i?

@greybeard My bad I just changed it!

@greybeard thanks should be all fixed now

The bound $0<i<10<j$ is equivalent to the two separate bounds $i<10$ and $10<j$. No specific relation between $i$ and $j$ is implied.
Thus the number of possibilities for $i$ is finite. How does the language look for exactly one of the values for $i$, say $i=4$?
Is that language context-free?

I was able to create a CFG for i=4:
\begin{align*}
S &\to \text{aaaa}B \
B &\to bB\text{cccc} \mid \lambda
\end{align*}
but how would I write this as formal proof? Do I just make a CFG for every i?

@Invictus: What about the concatenation of two CFLs? (The grammar may need handwaving, or a way to keep $10 \lt j$.)

@Invictus Good start. Yes, in principle you make a grammar for each $i$. Clearly that would be a lot of writing. Since the grammars have the same structure you can use $i$ as a parameter. Like: from $S\to a^4B$ move to $S\to a^i B_i$ for $i=\dots$. Don't forget $j> 10$.

@HendrikJan so if that proves that it's context free, can I transform the grammar into regular grammar and also prove that it's regular?

@Invictus Whether that is possible, is another question. But in case you succeed, yes then the language is of course regular.
